# Responsiveness of Website : Fit To Window or 100%?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

while using "inspect" to add media query for responsiveness of website, the percentage should be set to "Fit to window" or 100% ?

I tried building responsiveness for Samsung Galaxy S8+ with dimensions 360x740. It by default has the option "Fit To Window (65%) selected but on some YouTube tutorials, I saw people using 100% option instead. So I just wanted to know if I should be going with the Fit To Window or 100%.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: It sounds as though what you are talking about are just the options your browser is giving you for what it should show you when you are using its inspect facility - nothing to do with CSS. Is that right? If so it's just a choice when in inspect. However, if you are having a problem with a CSS media query please put the relevant code into your question as in @Sfili_81 comment.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.